# Piecewise functions in MATLAB. Help!

Tags: matlab, piecewise-continuity

I am trying to plot a pretty repetitive function in MATLAB. The values of $f$ are the same each $y$ for a designated season in the year. We have a function $f(t)$ and:

$$ f(t) = \begin{cases}
500 & \text{ if } 0 \le x < 91 \\ 
1500 & \text{ if } 91 \le x < 182 \\ 
500 & \text{ if } 182 \le x < 273 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } 273 \le x < 365
\end{cases} $$

I am able to plot this for one year using a piecewise function. But I am wondering how to extend this further. What if I want to plot this for a period of ten years, without having to manually input the values of $t$? Is there something that I can use, like an `elseif` function? I am quite confused on how to do this.

So far, I have been using a piecewise function and manually inputting the values of $t$ is getting very tedious.

For example, I have:

$f = {\tt piecewise}(0 \le t<91,500,91 \le t<182,1500,182 \le t<273,500,273 \le t<365,0,365 \le t<456,500,456 \le t<547,1500,547 \le t<638,500,638 \le t<730,0,730 \le t<821,500,821 \le t<912,1500,912 \le t<1003,500,1003 \le t<1095,0);      $

Just wondering if there is an easier way to do this.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm sorry for the somewhat blunt question, but have you ever considered to read a manual/tutorial?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 2):

It can be useful to represent your function *analytically* as a sum of functions each of which has a factor of a "Heaviside function". This is standard in the use of Laplace transforms in differential equations, for instance. For example your function can be written as $500+1000\theta(x-91)-1000\theta(x-182)-500\theta(x-273)$, where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside function. (It may take some work to ensure that you have the desired behavior *exactly* at each "transition point", if you care about that.) This is not essential to what you're trying to do if you already have the piecewise function defined for a single period in another way.

Once you have your function f defined for one period, taking the periodic extension is as simple as considering f(mod(x,365)) (in Matlab notation). Most other programming languages (C,Python,...) use an operator % instead of a function "mod", so you would write f(x%365) in such languages.

Comment: And the Heaviside function $\theta(x -a)$ is as simple as `(x >= a)` in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 12 segments, so I'd make an input num_segments=12; and an input t_length=92; as finally an array y_result=[500,1500,500,0]; (and so on). Then, in your function, you have, say, a for loop, with i=0:num_segments-1 and then on each iteration, programmatically define t_lengthi<=t(i+1) and extract y_result[i]. Does that help?

I apologize for the bad formatting and if my syntax is wrong on defining arrays. I work in multiple languages and always forget which one uses brackets vs. parentheses for different things.